# JSON count only returns 1 instead of 2

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have this line of code (which always returns 1):

```
int rowsCount = token["rows"].Count();
```

Where token["rows"] is:

```
    {
  "component": [
    {
      "tag": "CUT",
      "missingValue": "",
      "format": "Cont",
      "varName": "GPA",
      "label": "Grade point average",
      "element": [
        {
          "startValue": "1",
          "endValue": "249",
          "label": "Lower than 2.50"
        },
        {
          "startValue": "250",
          "endValue": "299",
          "label": "2.50 - 2.99"
        },
        {
          "startValue": "300",
          "endValue": "349",
          "label": "3.00 - 3.49"
        },
        {
          "startValue": "350",
          "endValue": "400",
          "label": "3.50 or higher"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "CAT",
      "missingValue": "",
      "format": "Disc",
      "varName": "STEMMAJ",
      "label": "Major field of study with a focus on STEM fields",
      "element": [
        {
          "value": "1",
          "label": "Math/Computer/Sciences/Engineering/Technologies"
        },
        {
          "value": "2",
          "label": "Social/behavioral sciences"
        },
        {
          "value": "4",
          "label": "Non-STEM field"
        },
        {
          "value": "5",
          "label": "Undecided or not in a degree program"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get a count of the number of components.

This isn't working either:

```
token["rows"]["component"].Count();
```

The entire JSON is here:

```
    {
  "version": "1.0",
  "createdBy": "PowerStats v1.0",
  "test": "ohoh",
  "DSNumber": {
    "value": "82"
  },
  "title": {
    "value": ""
  },
  "footnote": {
    "value": ""
  },
  "flagRSE": {
    "value": "30,50",
    "symbol": "!,!!"
  },
  "weight": {
    "type": "0",
    "varName": "WTA000",
    "label": "weight_var"
  },
  "filters": {
    "filter_1": {
      "component": {
        "varName": "JOBEARN2",
        "filterType": "Range",
        "format": "Cont",
        "label": "Job: Earnings from work while enrolled (including work-study)",
        "element": {
          "startValue": "1",
          "endValue": "",
          "label": "X >= 1"
        }
      }
    },
    "filter_2": {
      "component": {
        "varName": "JOBROLE2",
        "filterType": "Dist",
        "format": "Disc",
        "label": "Job: Primary role as student or employee (including work-study)",
        "element": {
          "value": "1",
          "label": "A student working to meet expenses"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "columns": {
    "component": {
      "tag": "CAT",
      "missingValue": "4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,-3",
      "format": "Disc",
      "varName": "MAJORS23",
      "label": "Field of study: undergraduate (23 categories)",
      "element": [
        {
          "value": "0",
          "label": "Undecided"
        },
        {
          "value": "1",
          "label": "Computer and information sciences"
        },
        {
          "value": "2",
          "label": "Engineering and engineering technology"
        },
        {
          "value": "3",
          "label": "Biological and physical science, science tech"
        },
        {
          "value": "11",
          "label": "Personal and consumer services"
        },
        {
          "value": "12",
          "label": "Manufacturing,construction,repair & transportation"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "rows": {
    "component": [
      {
        "tag": "CUT",
        "missingValue": "",
        "format": "Cont",
        "varName": "GPA",
        "label": "Grade point average",
        "element": [
          {
            "startValue": "1",
            "endValue": "249",
            "label": "Lower than 2.50"
          },
          {
            "startValue": "250",
            "endValue": "299",
            "label": "2.50 - 2.99"
          },
          {
            "startValue": "300",
            "endValue": "349",
            "label": "3.00 - 3.49"
          },
          {
            "startValue": "350",
            "endValue": "400",
            "label": "3.50 or higher"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "tag": "CAT",
        "missingValue": "",
        "format": "Disc",
        "varName": "STEMMAJ",
        "label": "Major field of study with a focus on STEM fields",
        "element": [
          {
            "value": "1",
            "label": "Math/Computer/Sciences/Engineering/Technologies"
          },
          {
            "value": "2",
            "label": "Social/behavioral sciences"
          },
          {
            "value": "4",
            "label": "Non-STEM field"
          },
          {
            "value": "5",
            "label": "Undecided or not in a degree program"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you use to parse the JSON? And maybe a complete/correct JSON excerpt? This way we don't have to reconstruct the structure.

Comment: Given the above JSON as the contents of `token["rows"]`, then `Count()` is correctly returning 1.  There's only one child, the `component` property.  You'll have to explain what you mean by "this isn't working" for the second part.  I get 2 for the count of children of the `component` property.

Comment: How do you just count the children?

Comment: .Children().Count() of rows still gives me 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comments in another answer, I can see now why you are confused.  You did not mention  that you are doing XML to JSON transformation in your question.

As I'm sure you are aware, XML doesn't have the concept of an "object" or an "array" like JSON does.  In XML, everything is just a collection of named nodes.  When deciding on whether something should be an array or an object, JSON.net looks at whether there are multiple nodes at the same level with the same name.  If there are, those are clearly an array.  But if a node has only a single child, it is ambiguous.  It could be an array of one item, or it could be just a simple object property.  By default, Json.Net chooses the latter.  If the number of results in your XML can vary from zero to many, this can make things more difficult to deal with when converted to JSON.

To illustrate, consider the following XML.  In it, we have three different "collections", each with a different number of "items" in it.  The first collection has just one child; the second has two, and the last is empty.

```
<root>
    <collection1>
        <item>
            <label>A</label>
            <value>1</value>
        </item>
    </collection1>
    <collection2>
        <item>
            <label>B</label>
            <value>2</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <label>C</label>
            <value>3</value>
        </item>
    </collection2>
    <collection3 />
</root>
```

When transformed using [`JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode()`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeXmlNode_2.htm), we get this JSON:

```
{
  "collection1": {
    "item": {
      "label": "A",
      "value": "1"
    }
  },
  "collection2": {
    "item": [
      {
        "label": "B",
        "value": "2"
      },
      {
        "label": "C",
        "value": "3"
      }
    ]
  },
  "collection3": null
}
```

Notice that in the first collection, the item has become a property of the parent collection object, while in the second case, the items are placed in an array, and that array has become the value of an `item` property on the parent object.  (In other words, the actual items are *one level further down* in the JSON structure!)  The last collection does not have an `item` property at all; it has a value of `null` instead.

So how do we deal with this?  What we really need is a helper method that will handle all these varying cases and give us back a collection of items (e.g. a `JArray`) that we can work with consistently.

Here's an extension method that should work:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static JArray ToJArray(this JToken token, string itemProperty)
    {
        if (token != null && token.Type != JTokenType.Null)
        {
            token = token[itemProperty];
            if (token != null)
            {
                if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
                {
                    return (JArray)token;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new JArray(token);
                }
            }
        }
        return new JArray();
    }
}
```

Here's a demo showing how we can use this helper method to print out the lists of items:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
          ""collection1"": {
            ""item"": {
              ""label"": ""A"",
              ""value"": ""1""
            }
          },
          ""collection2"": {
            ""item"": [
              {
                ""label"": ""B"",
                ""value"": ""2""
              },
              {
                ""label"": ""C"",
                ""value"": ""3""
              }
            ]
          },
          ""collection3"": null
        }";

        JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);

        DumpItems(root, "collection1");
        DumpItems(root, "collection2");
        DumpItems(root, "collection3");
    }

    private static void DumpItems(JToken token, string collectionName)
    {
        JArray array = token[collectionName].ToJArray("item");

        Console.WriteLine("Count of items in " + collectionName + ": " + array.Count);
        foreach (JToken item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["label"] + ": " + item["value"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Count of items in collection1: 1
A: 1
Count of items in collection2: 2
B: 2
C: 3
Count of items in collection3: 0
```

Going back to your original question, you should now be able to do this:

```
var count = token["rows"].ToJArray("component").Count;
```

and get the value you expect.

Comment: really great answer, i wish i could do this out of the box with biztalk or xslt?

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

```
int rowsCount = token["rows"]["component"].Count();
```

WILL give you the correct answer.

I tested with this code:

```
var token = JObject.Parse(...your pasted JSON...);
int rowsCount = token["rows"]["component"].Count();
```

Comment: but what happens when there is only 1 component, then it will give me the elements in the column correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If there is a single component, the count will be one as the component should still be in an array ([]), which has one element.

Comment: To access the first element, you would need to do token["rows"]["component"][0] or token["rows"]["component"].First()

Comment: When I used JSON.Net to transform XML to JSON it doesn't put single components into an array, like so: ..."columns": {
    "component": {
      "tag": "CAT",...

Comment: if it were in an array this would be easy

Answer (score 0):

You should paste on http://jsonlint.com/ for indention which could help.

The problem is because... well it IS one. "rows" json is `"rows": {` which mean... its a terrible name. Rows here is an object (see the `{`). It isn't an array. Theres only one. What you want is likely component inside of rows. Perhaps the json generation is wrong but one is the correct answer.