# How do you tell if a JSON object is an array or not?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json, json.net

I have transformed my XML into JSON using .ToJSON() from JSON.NET

This turns things with multiple xml elements of 2 or more into arrays, while singe elements aren't.

```
<trendstats>
        <paramFile version=\"1.0\" createdBy=\"PowerStats v1.0\" test=\"ohoh\">
        </paramFile>
</trendstats>
```

becomes:

```
"trendstats": {
    "paramFile": {
```

While:

```
<trendstats>
        <paramFile version=\"1.0\" createdBy=\"PowerStats v1.0\" test=\"ohoh\">
        </paramFile>
        <paramFile version=\"1.0\" createdBy=\"PowerStats v1.0\" test=\"ohoh\">
        </paramFile>
</trendstats>
```

becomes:

```
"trendstats": {
    "paramFile": [ {
```

How can I tell them apart?

Comment: For others who might find it useful: in addition to the answers on this page, see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20158103/10263) to @chris's related question, which explains why this situation occurs and gives an alternative solution for handling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [page](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) shows you how to tell JSON.NET to force xml elements to always produce arrays. That way, you won't have to guess what type it is.

Comment: I'm using JSON.NET I don't have a length property.  JToken token = JObject.Parse(json); and then using token[".."].lenght doesn't exist

Comment: Got it. http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html search for "attribute to force" it will solve the problem you have of either array or object.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it, am I missing something?

Comment: line 23 of the section "Attribute to Force a JSON Array": `<role json:Array='true'>Admin</role>`

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the assertion that C# doesn't have a length propery...  if so what is going on here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it does have a length property but we aren't using arrays. We are using tokens from JSON.NET which is a class

Comment: It works when I added the xmlns and json: force arrays to the components and then parsing works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it looks to me like you have a couple of options:

1. Find out how many elements are in paramFile.  I can't help wondering if it has a .Length rather than a .length (case). This would suggest it does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx
2. Force it to become one or the other by altering the xml as suggested by rdodev.
3. Force it to become one or the other in c# - although by the time you do this and figure out what kind of errors it gives you, you're going to have a test you can work with.

I'm not a C# programmer, but the question caught my interest.