# xml to json using newtonsoft issue when loop over array of one element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, json.net

i get error only when in the source xml there is a collection of only one element, 
in the sample for the first element i get correctly the subelements (item) but in the second element there's only one child so the code throw exception (Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)

Thanks

```
JObject firstLevels = new JObject();
string sourceXML = "<Root>
                        <FirstLevel id=\"1\" name=\"1\">
                            <Item id=\"1\" name=\"1.1\" />
                                <Item id=\"2\" name=\"1.2\" />
                        </FirstLevel>
                        <FirstLevel id=\"2\" name=\"2\">
                            <Item id=\"1\" name=\"2.1\" />
                        </FirstLevel>
                    </Root>";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(sourceXML);
XmlNodeList nodeList;
nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Root/FirstLevel");
JArray jarray = new JArray();

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(node);
    jarray.Add(JObject.Parse(json));
}

firstLevels["result"] = jarray;

foreach(var first in firstLevels["result"].Children<JObject>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(first["FirstLevel"]["@name"].Value<string>());

    foreach (var item in first["FirstLevel"]["Item"])
        Console.WriteLine(" -- " + item["@name"].Value<string>());
}
```

Comment: You can use a helper method to deal with this situation.  See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20158103/10263).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're doing this:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(node);
```

For these two nodes:

```
<FirstLevel id=\"1\" name=\"1\">
    <Item id=\"1\" name=\"1.1\" />
        <Item id=\"2\" name=\"1.2\" />
</FirstLevel>

<FirstLevel id=\"2\" name=\"2\">
    <Item id=\"1\" name=\"2.1\" />
</FirstLevel>
```

Now, in the second case JSON .Net can't know whether to create a collection with a single element in it or just a single element (i.e. { a: {}} or { a: [{}]}) so it converts it to a single object.

This is not really what you're expecting though.  You need it to always be an array to make your JSON consistent.  There is this question already around this stuff:  [JSON.Net Xml Serialization misunderstands arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488662/json-net-xml-serialization-misunderstands-arrays) that could be worth a read.

You, therefore, have a few choices I think:

---

**Adjust your XML to give JSON .Net a hint on What to Do**

To do this, you need to add a namespace to the root node (`xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'`) and an attribute to the nodes you want to participate in the array (`json:Array='true'`).

For example:

```
string sourceXML = "<Root xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'><FirstLevel id=\"1\" name=\"1\"><Item json:Array='true' id=\"1\" name=\"1.1\" /><Item json:Array='true' id=\"2\" name=\"1.2\" /></FirstLevel><FirstLevel id=\"2\" name=\"2\"><Item json:Array='true' id=\"1\" name=\"2.1\" /></FirstLevel></Root>";
```

Details here: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/ConvertingJSONandXML.html

---

**Put in a Dummy Node to Force JSON .NET to Serialize to an Array**

I don't really like this but if you cannot adjust the XML changing your code to something like this will do the trick:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{        
    string json;
    if (node.SelectNodes("Item").Count == 1)
    {
        // Append a dummy node and then strip it out - horrible!
        node.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateNode("element", "Item", ""));
        json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(node).Replace(",null]", "]");
    }
    else
    {
        json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(node);                    
    }

    jarray.Add(JObject.Parse(json));
}
```

---

**Check When you Read**

Of course, you could just check the type when you handle your data, like so:

```
foreach (var first in firstLevels["result"].Children<JObject>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(first["FirstLevel"]["@name"].Value<string>());

    if (first["FirstLevel"]["Item"] is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" -- " + first["FirstLevel"]["Item"]["@name"].Value<string>());
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in first["FirstLevel"]["Item"])
            Console.WriteLine(" -- " + item["@name"].Value<string>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this xml to json conversion manually

```
string sourceXML = "<Root><FirstLevel id=\"1\" name=\"1\"><Item id=\"1\" name=\"1.1\" /><Item id=\"2\" name=\"1.2\" /></FirstLevel><FirstLevel id=\"2\" name=\"2\"><Item id=\"1\" name=\"2.1\" /></FirstLevel></Root>";

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(XDocument.Parse(sourceXML));
```

or to get a json array

```
var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(XDocument.Parse(sourceXML)
                                                 .Descendants("FirstLevel"));
```