# Convert XML to Json Array when only one object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json, json.net

I am currently using Newtonsoft to convert some xml to json to return from a RestExtension.

My xml is in the form of

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Name>name</Name>
    <Detail>detail</Detail>    
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Name>name</Name>
    <Detail>detail</Detail>    
  </Item>
</Items>
```

I convert this to json using

```
JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmldocument);
```

This works fine if there is more than one item.

I get this - an array of items in json (which is what I need):

```
{"Items":{"Item":[{"Name":"name","Detail":"detail"},{"Name":"name","Detail":"detail"}]}}
```

But when there is only one it quite understandably converts like this (not an array):

```
 {"Items":{"Item":{"Name":"name","Detail":"detail"}}}
```

My app developer who is reading this needs the json to return an array of items regardless or whether there is one or more.

Is there a way of tricking it into thinking it's an array or can someone suggest another way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry What do you want to be an array not sure I followed the question properly

Comment: sorry I've edited to hopefully make it clearer. I need an array of items.

Comment: @DJkraze he has done the conversion he just needs needs it it a different format

Comment: @DJKRAZE, the link you sent is exactly what I am doing. I just need it differently. Unless I am totally missing the point, please either explain or be kind enough to retract your down vote.

Comment: ok can you do something like the following since I can't tell which format is correct or not from your question 

`XmlNote myXmlNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(yourJsonString);
// or .DeserilizeXmlNode(myJsonString, "root"); // if yourJsonString does not have a root`
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(myXmlNode);

Comment: Bex.. I didn't downvote you..

Comment: you could also do the following as well 
`XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

// To convert JSON text contained in string json into an XML node
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);`

Comment: Sorry @DJKRAZE your comment and the vote appeared at the same time. Now it's gone. I shouldn't have assumed.
I don't think either of your comments will convert my xml to a json array of items when there is only one item.

Comment: @Bex [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20158103/10263) might be of some help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Read this [documentation about Serialize Xml Node](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm)

You can force JSON Array this way

```
var xml = @"<Items xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json' >
             <Item json:Array='true'>
                <Name>name</Name>
                 <Detail>detail</Detail>    
            </Item>
            </Items>";
```

**[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jDUZ2k)**

Comment: that's great! Would you happen to know how you'd generate that with XElement as it doesn't like the ":"?

Comment: thanks I understand now.have put a post below how I'd do it with XElement rather than xmltextwritera and XDocument

Comment: This is a little difficult to do once the XML document is already in memory. However the namespace can be added to the node directly using the XmlNode.Attributes.Append(XMLAttribute) method. You will get: <Item json:Array='true' xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'> which will also work.

Comment: @meda How do you keep the json:Array attibutes when converting xml to json and then again to xml and back to json? Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48763666/7392294

Answer (score 4):

In case it helps anyone, further to meda's reply.
Here's how you make this work with XElement rather than xmlTextWriter and XDocument

```
XNamespace ns = "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json";
var items = new XElement("items",new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns+"json",ns));

   items.Add(new XElement("item",new XAttribute(ns+"Array",true),
                        new XElement("name", "name"),
                        new XElement("Detail", "detail")));
```

then to convert it

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(items.ToString());
            var converted JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library available to convert such xml into expected json format

```
string xml = @"<Items>
        <Item>
            <Name>name</Name>
            <Detail>detail</Detail>    
        </Item>
    </Items>";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var p = ChoXmlReader.LoadText(xml).WithXPath("/"))
{
    using (var w = new ChoJSONWriter(sb)
        .Configure(c => c.SupportMultipleContent = true)
        )
        w.Write(p);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Output:

```
{
 "Items": [
  {
    "Name": "name",
    "Detail": "detail"
  }
 ]
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WSDLReport
{
    private IEnumerable<WSDLDocument> _document;

    private void SetDocuments(dynamic documents)
    {
        var type = documents.GetType();

        if (type == typeof(JObject))
            _document = new List<WSDLDocument>() { ((JObject)documents).ToObject<WSDLDocument>() };
        else if (type == typeof(JArray))
            _document = ((JArray)documents).ToObject<IEnumerable<WSDLDocument>>();
        else
            _document = new List<WSDLDocument>();
    }

    private dynamic GetDocuments() => _document;

    [JsonProperty("dokumentyEzla")]
    public dynamic Document
    {
        get => GetDocuments();
        set => SetDocuments(value);
    }
}
```