# Single Element Nested Arrays in JSON from XML in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, xml, json.net

I am working with a JSON object that I am serializing from XML. All the child nodes of the XML need to be serialized as arrays.  I have been trying this for a couple days now and have found nothing, but I have gotten close.  The problem is that JsonConvert.SerializeObject() seems to be seeing this as a single item array, and then removing the [] array indicators in the JSON.  Here is my example of what I have been doing.

The desired result is this:

```
{"Foo":[{"Bar":[{"This":"stuff"}]}]}
```

What has gotten me the closest so far is something like this...

```
        XElement bar = new XElement("Bar");
        bar.SetAttributeValue("This", "stuff");
        XElement[] foo = { new XElement("Foo", bar) };
```

But it still is not quite right.  The result I get here after running `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo)` is something like this...

```
{"Foo":{"Bar":{"This":"stuff"}}}
```

For the API, each child of the parent has to be an array type, even if it only  contains 1 element.  The XML version of this request, which I can't use, looks like this...

```
 <Foo>
  <Bar This="stuff"/>
 </Foo>
```

I have a feeling I'm overlooking something simple, or making this more complex than it needs to be, but I could really use some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're using Newtonsoft's library. Rather than building the JSON objects yourself, you could build nested `Dictonary`s and arrays of `Dictionary`s, and let `JsonConvert.Tostring` do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: If it works, let me know and I'll write up an answer for you ;)

Comment: I had tried something similar already and ended up with a conversion error, it looked like this. `Dictionary<string,string> dic = new Dictionary<string,string>(); dic.add("This","stuff"); Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> dic2 = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>(); dic2.add("Bar", dic);`

Comment: I kept getting a type conversion error on execution, but dictionaries in C# are not my strong suit.  Prefer Python for that kind of stuff.  Is there a different way to structure the second dictionary that won't break?

Comment: Refer to this one: [convert-xml-to-json-array-when-only-one-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612835/convert-xml-to-json-array-when-only-one-object) And use JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(...)

Comment: Re: your use of `Dictionary`s: you need to use arrays of `Dictionary`s to get it working. A single `Dictionary` always converts to a JSON object, never to a JSON array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hunts Chen in the comments had the redirect that solved my issue.  Here is what the working code ended up looking like.

```
        XNamespace ns = "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json";

        XElement bar = new XElement("Bar");
        userdata.SetAttributeValue(ns + "Array", true);
        userdata.SetAttributeValue("This", "stuff");
        XElement foo = new XElement("Foo", bar);
        parts.SetAttributeValue(ns+"Array", true);

        XDocument xmlbody = new XDocument();

        xmlbody.Add(foo);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xmlbody);
```

Since there is only a single element for each node, the array has to be forced.  The return was exactly what I was intending.

```
 {"Foo":[{"Bar":[{"@This":"stuff"}]}]}}
```

Thanks!