# Web API response XML/JSON instead of string

Tags: c#, json, xml, api

I'm trying to create a web API. The problem I'm having is that I'm responding with a string instead of a better formatted response so the application using the API can parse it easier.

**Is there a way to return something better formatted, like JSON or XML? And How do I do that?**

```
  public string Get(string id)
    {
        XElement xelement = XElement.Load("C:/Users/potter/source/repos/library/lib/Controllers/books.xml");
        var books = xelement.Elements("book").Where(x => x.Element("title").ToString().ToLower().Contains(id));
        foreach (XElement xEle in books)
        {          
            returnValue = returnValue + xEle.ToString();    
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: Please check answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612835/convert-xml-to-json-array-when-only-one-object

Comment: What is the XML input and what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: XML input is my data source and is formatted like this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256479(v=vs.110).aspx Now I'm trying to respond a specific book to the application as a formatted format instead of a string with bunch of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hi Couple of points -*

1. > **Is there a way to return something better formatted, like JSON or XML?**
   >   **And How do I do that?**

From WEB API perspective  if the object is serializable then it will automatically convert to well formatted XML or JSON. So instead of returning a *string* return the "books" which is an IEnumerable in this case so you don't have to worry about formatting.

*You may have to also see these below discussions on the same  --*

[WebAPI to Return XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662028/webapi-to-return-xml)

2. > **You are trying to fetch specific books based on title**

Would also want to suggest instead of checking against Value instead of XmlElement, So replace the below line

```
x => x.Element("title").ToString().ToLower().Contains(id)
```

with -

```
x => x.Element("title").Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(id)
```

So the final code which you would be writing is for list of specific ***books*** -

```
 public IEnumerable<XElement> Get(string id)
        {

            XElement xelement = XElement.Load("C:/Users/potter/source/repos/library/lib/Controllers/books.xml");
            return xelement.Elements("book").Where(x => x.Element("title").Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(id));
        }
```

Once you have this set up in server side then you can call the API from client side using jQuery ajax something like below -

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:50116/api/values/GetData/",//Change this to your URL
        cache: false,
        data: {id:'xml'},//Title has this word 'xml'
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('book').each(function () {
                var name = $(this).find("title").text();
                var genre = $(this).find("genre").text();
                var price = $(this).find("price").text();
                var description = $(this).find("description").text();
                alert(name);
                alert(genre);
                alert(price);
                alert(description);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is excatly waht I'm looking for! Also Could I ask what the code on the View side would look like to get a specific element, lets say author? data["author"] ?

Comment: From view side how are you planning to call the API? Jquery Ajax?

Comment: Jquery with ajax indeed

Comment: Updated my answer please have a look!